# htaccess not redirecting to full url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm just starting to learn how to use .htaccess so I'm trying a basic redirect but it doesn't redirect to the exact url I'm asking it to.

User Types: `http://sample.com/account`

Redirect To: `http://sample.com/account.php#login`

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteRule ^account/?$ account.php#login [NC,L]
```

But it instead just reroutes to `http://sample.com/account/` without the `#login` part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect you must use `R` flag and also you should use `NE` flag to avoid escaping of `NE`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^account/?$ /account.php#login [NC,L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Since it's an _external redirect_, you'll also need a slash prefix on the substitution to avoid the directory-prefix being added. (Or set `RewriteBase /`)

Comment: Absolutely correct, thanks. It was silly on my part to overlook that part.